# using an interface with multiple classes in java

Tags: java

My code for my program is below.  The issue I am having "machine" in line 38 and 44 is showing an error stating "machine cannot be resolved".  When the program starts I need to create an instance of the second vending machine type and allow the user to choose which of the two vending machines to use when choosing to dispense or refill.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    out.println("(G)umball machine or (S)oda Machine: ");
    String choice1 = input.nextLine();
    
    if(choice1.toLowerCase().equals("g")) {
        GumballMachine machine = new GumballMachine();
        machine.refill(0);
        machine.dispense();
        machine.isEmpty();
    }
    if(choice1.toLowerCase().equals("s")) {
        SodaMachine machine = new SodaMachine();
        machine.refill(0);
        machine.dispense();
        machine.isEmpty();
    }
    else
        out.println("Invalid choice");
    
    
    while(true) {

        out.print("(V)end, (R)efill or (E)xit: ");
        String choice = input.nextLine();

        if(choice.toLowerCase().equals("v")) {
            out.println(machine.dispense());  //getting machine cannot be resolved
        }
        else if (choice.toLowerCase().equals("r")) {
            out.print("Enter amount to refull: ");
            int amount = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            machine.refill(amount);  //getting machine cannot be resolved
            out.println("Refilled...");
        }
        else if (choice.toLowerCase().equals("e")) {
            break;
        }
        else
            out.println("Invalid choice");
    }

}   
}
```

Comment: Okay, and where do you define `machine`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I though i defined it after the user enters either a g or s GumballMachine machine = new GumballMachine();                                   
SodaMachine machine = new SodaMachine();

Comment: @Andy I tired to make it visible and make it bold.  it surrounded itself with **

Answer (score 3):

So, your problem is, `machine` is undefined within the context that you're trying to use it.

> I though i defined it after the user enters either a g or s GumballMachine machine = new GumballMachine(); SodaMachine machine = new SodaMachine();

```
if(choice1.toLowerCase().equals("g")) {
    GumballMachine machine = new GumballMachine();
    machine.refill(0);
    machine.dispense();
    machine.isEmpty();
}
if(choice1.toLowerCase().equals("s")) {
    SodaMachine machine = new SodaMachine();
    machine.refill(0);
    machine.dispense();
    machine.isEmpty();
}
```

So, `machine` is only defined within the context between the `{...}` and can only be used within that context.

In order to overcome this issue, and probably the point of the exercise, you need to pre-define `machine` to match the minimum expected requirements of the rest of the code, in your case, that would be `VendingMachine`

That would make the code look something more like...

```
VendingMachine machine = null;

if (choice1.toLowerCase().equals("g")) {
    machine = new GumballMachine();
    machine.refill(0);
    machine.dispense();
    machine.isEmpty();
}
if (choice1.toLowerCase().equals("s")) {
    machine = new SodaMachine();
    machine.refill(0);
    machine.dispense();
    machine.isEmpty();
} else {
    out.println("Invalid choice");
}

while (true) {

    out.print("(V)end, (R)efill or (E)xit: ");
    String choice = input.nextLine();

    if (choice.toLowerCase().equals("v")) {
        out.println(machine.dispense());
    } else if (choice.toLowerCase().equals("r")) {
        out.print("Enter amount to refull: ");
        int amount = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        machine.refill(amount);
        out.println("Refilled...");
    } else if (choice.toLowerCase().equals("e")) {
        break;
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid choice");
    }
}
```

Now, remember, this will limit you to the functionality defined by `VendingMachine`, but seems to be the point of the exercise.

Comment: The "s" check should probably be an else if.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Fair point, but can't do everything for them :P